# Using Variables in a form

Tags: javascript, forms, user-input

PLEASE HELP! I am very new to JavaScript, and I am completely stuck on why my code is not producing an output. The object of my assignment is to accept a users input into a pre-established form. Once the user clicks submit the pre-established form will replace key variables with the users input. Here is my source code and js:

Code and js:
    `

```js
function showFormInput() { //get data from the form
  var a1 = document.getElementsById('rname').value;
  var b2 = document.getElementsById('orgname').value;
  var c3 = document.getElementsById('date').value;
  var d4 = document.getElementsById('web').value;
  var e5 = document.getElementsById('hname').value;
  
  // Displaying data in the HTML
  document.getElementById('recipientName').innerHTML = a1;
  document.getElementById('organizationName').innerHTML = b2;
  document.getElementById('eventDate').innerHTML = c3;
  document.getElementById('websiteURL').innerHTML = d4;
  document.getElementById('hostName').innerHTML = e5;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="top">
    <a class="logo" href="index.html">CapellaVolunteers<span 
    class="dotcom">.org</span></a>
  </div>
  <nav>
    <ul class="topnav">
      <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="invitation.html" class="active">Invitation</a></li>
      <li><a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
      <li><a href="registration.html">Registration</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
<section id="pageForm">
  <label for="recipientName">Recipient name:</label>
  <input type="text" id="rname" name="recipientName" placeholder="Enter your 
    Recipient Name" />
  <label for="organizationName">Organization name:</label>
  <input type="text" id="orgname" name="organizationName" placeholder="Enter 
    your Organization Name" />
  <label for="eventDate">Event Date:</label>
  <input type="text" id="date" name="eventDate" placeholder="Enter your 
    Event Date" />
  <label for="websiteURL">URL:</label>
  <input type="text" id="web" name="websiteURL" placeholder="Enter your 
    Website URL" />
  <label for="hostName">Host name:</label>
  <input type="text" id="hname" name="hostName" placeholder="Host Name" />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="showFormInput()" />
</section>
<article id="placeholderContent">
  Hello
  <span id="recipientName">recipientName</span>!
  <br/>
  <br/> You have been invited to volunteer for an event held by
  <span id="organizationName">organizationName</span> on
  <span id="eventDate">eventDate</span>. Please come to the following website:
  <span id="websiteURL">websiteURL</span> to sign up as a volunteer.
  <br/>
  <br/> Thanks!
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <span id="hostName">hostName</span>
</article>
<footer>This events site is for IT-FP3215 tasks.</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems to work after a few fixes after running it through a linter.

A couple of the issues:

- You meant `getElementById` (not `getElementsById`)
- The bottom half of the code was wrapped in a `{}` block (not sure why). It needs to all be in the same block if it should run on click.
- Comments start with two forward slashed: (`//`).

```js
function showFormInput() { //get data from the form
    var a1 = document.getElementById('rname').value; // 'rname reference id in html(not included with html you will need to add.)
    var b2 = document.getElementById('orgname').value;
    var c3 = document.getElementById('date').value;
    var d4 = document.getElementById('web').value;
    var e5 = document.getElementById('hname').value;
    
    document.getElementById('recipientName').innerHTML = a1; // 'recipientName reference name in the html
    document.getElementById('organizationName').innerHTML = b2;
    document.getElementById('eventDate').innerHTML = c3;
    document.getElementById('websiteURL').innerHTML = d4;
    document.getElementById('hostName').innerHTML = e5;
}

document.getElementById('showFormInput').addEventListener('click', showFormInput);

// You can leave this in the <script> tags with an inline `onclick=` if needed (though I wouldn't recommend it). Just easier to edit in the JS.
```

```html
<html lang="en-US">
   <head>
      <title>Invitation Page</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css" />
   </head>
   <body>
      <header>
         <div class="top">
            <a class="logo" href="index.html">CapellaVolunteers<span 
               class="dotcom">.org</span></a>
         </div>
         <nav>
            <ul class="topnav">
               <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
               <li><a href="invitation.html" class="active">Invitation</a></li>
               <li><a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
               <li><a href="registration.html">Registration</a></li>
            </ul>
         </nav>
      </header>
      <section id="pageForm">
         <label for="recipientName">Recipient name:</label>
         <input type="text" id="rname" name="recipientName" placeholder="Enter your Recipient Name" />
         <label for="organizationName">Organization name:</label>
         <input type="text" id="orgname" name="organizationName" placeholder="Enter your Organization Name" />
         <label for="eventDate">Event Date:</label>
         <input type="text" id="date" name="eventDate" placeholder="Enter your Event Date" />
         <label for="websiteURL">URL:</label>
         <input type="text" id="web" name="websiteURL" placeholder="Enter your Website URL" />
         <label for="hostName">Host name:</label>
         <input type="text" id="hname" name="hostName" placeholder="Host Name" />
         <input type="submit" id='showFormInput' value="Submit" />
      </section>
      <article id="placeholderContent">
         Hello
         <span id="recipientName">recipientName</span>!
         <br/>
         <br/> You have been invited to volunteer for an event held by
         <span id="organizationName">organizationName</span> on
         <span id="eventDate">eventDate</span>. Please come to the following 
         website:
         <span id="websiteURL">websiteURL</span> to sign up as a volunteer.
         <br/>
         <br/> Thanks!
         <br/>
         <br/>
         <span id="hostName">hostName</span>
      </article>
      <footer>This events site is for IT-FP3215 tasks.</footer>
   </body>
</html>
```